# Rust serializes different than python? || Change Endianess in bincode

Tags: python, serialization, rust, tcp

I'm new to Rust but not to programming.
So I try to send data to a server via TCPStream (server is able to respond with 500Hz running on a robot)

I got a working example python-program from the company which builds the robots.

The problem:
After a couple of days and reading the documentation over and over again I measured a specific situation with wireshark.

So I know that **the working python-program sends 00 05 56 00 02** to the server which is correct

> 05 = packet size,
> 56 = the requested action to do,
> 02 = the data to be requested

my rust program sends **05 00 56 02 00** and I can't figure out why

```rust
    mod rtde_setup;
    mod package_types;

    use std::io::{Read, Write};
    use std::mem;
    use std::net::{TcpStream};
    // use serde_derive::{Serialize, Deserialize};
    use crate::package_types::*;
    use crate::rtde_setup::*;

    fn main() {
        #[allow(dead_code)]
        static ADDR: &str = "10.0.0.164";
        static PORT: &str = "30004";

        let mut set_protocol_version = RequestProtocolVersion {
            header: Header {
                package_size: 5,
                package_type: RTDE_REQUEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION,
            },
            protocol_version: 2,
        };


        //Python sends 00 05 56 00 02 bei 'V'
        //Rust sends 05 00 56 02 00 bei 'V'

        //header ist 3 byte
        //set_protocol_version.protocol_version ist 2
        let mut payload = (set_protocol_version);

        match TcpStream::connect(format!("{}:{}", ADDR, PORT)) {
            Ok(mut stream) => {
                stream.set_nodelay(true).expect("set_nodelay call failed");
                println!("Successfully connected to server {} on port {}", ADDR, PORT);
                let payload_byte: Vec<u8> = bincode::serialize(&payload).unwrap();

                stream.write(&payload_byte).unwrap();
                println!("Sent package (byte): {:?}", &payload_byte);
            }
            Err(e) => {
                println!("Failed to connect: {}", e);
            }
        }
        println!("Terminated.");
    }
```

```py
    def negotiate_protocol_version(self):
        cmd = Command.RTDE_REQUEST_PROTOCOL_VERSION
        payload = struct.pack('>H', RTDE_PROTOCOL_VERSION_2)
        success = self.__sendAndReceive(cmd, payload)
        if success:
            self.__protocolVersion = RTDE_PROTOCOL_VERSION_2
        return success
```

```py
    def __sendAndReceive(self, cmd, payload=b''):
        if self.__sendall(cmd, payload):
            return self.__recv(cmd)
        else:
            return None
```

---

[edit]
okay I tried to change the endianess with

```
let options = bincode::DefaultOptions::new().with_big_endian();
```

but the output is still the same...
so the options are

- I'm not able to understand the documentation
- it doesn't work

you're right with the Default endianess as little... so I hoped this would help.
maybe I'm just doing it wrong?

---

[edit]
worked!
thank you

I inserted

```
    let serialize_options = bincode::DefaultOptions::new()
    .with_fixint_encoding()
    .with_big_endian();
```

and edited

```
let payload_byte: Vec<u8> = serialize_options.serialize(&payload).unwrap();
```

now I sent **00 05 56 00 02** and got an answer from the server

next move will be deserializing with the new knowledge

Comment: Just guessing here, but that sounds like an endianness issue. If that turns out to be the case, you can configure that in `bincode`: https://docs.rs/bincode/latest/bincode/config/trait.Options.html#method.with_little_endian

Comment: Be careful with `bincode` it's only designed to work with `bincode` serialized/deserialized data.

Comment: Your python code sends data as big-endian ([because of the `>` in the call to `struct.pack`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html#byte-order-size-and-alignment)) but `bincode` uses native endianness by default, which most of the time means little-endian.

Comment: How do you serialize the data once you've called `with_big_endian`? You should serialize with `options.serialize (&payload)`, not `bincode::serialize`.

Comment: @Jmb => you're absolutely right. I did it and at the same time you wrote this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inserting

```
   let serialize_options = bincode::DefaultOptions::new()
    .with_fixint_encoding()
    .with_big_endian();
```

and editing

```
 let payload_byte: Vec<u8> = 
    serialize_options.serialize(&payload).unwrap();
```

worked for me

Big thanks to you

Comment: Hi. Could you please briefly explain, why it solved your issue?

Comment: Hi, as right-guessed above the rust code sent the bytes with small endian while the original python sent it in big endian. Setting the defaultOptions for bincode and used this "serialize_options" to serialize my payload. This solved the problem. I got an answer from the server and also as seen in wireshark the transferred bytes were the same as with python (I used a special example to know what has to be sent)